# Microsoft Teams Bot, HeroCard ActionTypes behaving differently

Tags: python, botframework, microsoft-teams, chatbot

I created a Bot wherein when a user types starts and then a hero card will be displayed where the user gets to select buttons in the hero card.

The problem here I am facing is that
When the user clicks on a button. It's value is being sent by users end automatically.

I want to store that value in a variable and use it somewhere else.
Please help me friends.

Below are the two major functions which I am using:

```
    async def on_message_activity(self, turn_context: TurnContext):
        """
        Respond to messages sent from the user.
        """
        # Get the state properties from the turn context.
        welcome_user_state = await self.user_state_accessor.get(
            turn_context, WelcomeUserState
        )
        list_items = []
        list_items.append(self.__send_intro_card())
        activity = MessageFactory.carousel(list_items)

        if not welcome_user_state.did_welcome_user:
            welcome_user_state.did_welcome_user = True
            
            name = turn_context.activity.from_property.name
            await turn_context.send_activity(
                f"Welcome {name}"
            )
        else:
            text = turn_context.activity.text.lower()
            if text in ("start"):
                await turn_context.send_activity(activity)
                print(activity)
            else:
                await turn_context.send_activity(self.START_AGAIN)

    def __send_intro_card(self) -> Attachment:
        access_token = request_access_token()
        sel_workspace_id = [
          {'id': '706c16bb-2295-41f5-af7b-530cbd643045', 'name': 'Aviation Solution'}, 
          {'id': '9a1c080d-855e-46e9-ac06-73746afdd65e', 'name': 'AviationSolutions'}
                  ]

        buttons = [
                CardAction(
                    type = ActionTypes.im_back,
                    title = workspace['name'],
                    text = workspace['name'],
                    display_text = workspace['name'],
                    value = workspace['id']
                ) for index, workspace in enumerate(sel_workspace_id)
            ]
        card = HeroCard(
            title="Select Your Workspace",
            text="You have access to the following workspaces:"
            "Please select the particular workspace on which you want get information.",
            buttons= buttons,
            )
        #await turn_context.send_activity(MessageFactory.attachment(CardFactory.hero_card(card)))
        return CardFactory.hero_card(card)
```

The bot is working something like this
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyK2x.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgS9O.png)

..................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Could you please elaborate your requirement and share the repro steps, so that we can try it from our end.